# c++ reference copy trouble (stl pair)

Tags: c++, stl

I have difficults in implementing such thing:

```
int a = 5;
int& b = a;
pair <int, int> test;
test.first = b;
a = 1000;
```

`test.first` value doesn't change, obviously, but I want it to change, so I am trying to create `pair <int&, int&>`, but I can't because of compiler.

My aim is to get `test.first` changed, how can I implement it (**without using `int*` pointers, yes**) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store references in STL containers. The reason is because references can not be assigned after construction. References are always initialized to point to a certain object but can never be reassigned. Thus reference types do not fulfill the type requirements to be used inside containers. This is why your compiler complains.

If you want this kind of functionality, you will need to store pointers.

The following question is of a similar nature:
[stl-stores-references-or-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382628/stl-stores-references-or-values)

Comment: You're welcome! There is nothing wrong with using pointers, really. Please mark this question as answered if you are done.

Answer (score 5):

In C++11 you can use a `reference_wrapper`. Your code would become

```
#include <functional>
int a = 5;
auto b = ref(a);
b.get() = 3;
cout<<a<<endl;
pair <reference_wrapper<int>, int> test(b, 0);
a = 1000;
cout<<test.first<<endl;
```